# If you can reach a point in $R^4$ does that automatically mean that your set of vectors must be Linearly Independent in $R^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on part c) and given that we can reach a point $(1,1,1,1)$ does this mean we are linearly independent in $R^4$?

[image]

We can formulate this as a 4x6 matrix and as such the rank must be less than or equal to 4 but how do we know it is 4 without doing any calculations?

How do I determine the number of solutions in this scenario then? Because the system is not linearly independent in $R^6$ it means we can find some linear combination is zero.

I do not follow the reasoning given here:

[image]

This is not homework it is from the MIT course given by Strang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing out that $4 \times 6$ matrix gives $$\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&1&1&2\\ 0&0&1&1&2&0\\ 0&1&1&2&0&0\\ 1&1&2&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ You can see that this is similar to a matrix in echelon form (just put the rows in reverse order) with four pivot columns, i.e. four linearly independent vectors, so the rank is $4$.

Now, we’ve observed that $(2,-1,0,1,0,0)$ is a solution. In other words, $$2r_1 + (-1)r_2 + 0r_3 + 1r_4 + 0r_5 + 0r_6 = (1,1,1,1) \tag{1}.$$

On the other hand, as you observed, since there are $6$ vectors, they must be linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R}^4$, so there is $\alpha_1, …, \alpha_6$ not all zero such that $\alpha_1 r_1 + … + \alpha_6 r_6 = 0.$ Then note that, for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $t\alpha_1 r_1 + … + t\alpha_6 r_6 = t(\alpha_1 r_1 + … + \alpha_6 r_6) = t \cdot 0 = 0$ as well. Thus, $$(1,1,1,1) = \text{Equation 1} = \text{(Equation 1)} + 0 = \text{(Equation 1)} + (t\alpha_1 r_1 + … + t\alpha_6 r_6) = (2+t\alpha_1)r_1 + (-1+t\alpha_2)r_2 + (t\alpha_3) r_3+ (1+t\alpha_4)r_4 + (t\alpha_5)r_5 + (t\alpha_6)r_6.$$

Hence we have infinitely many solutions.

More generally, we have the following result: If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with $n > m$, then by the rank-nullity theorem, the null space of $A$ is non-zero, so in particular the null space has infinitely many vectors. So, if the system $Ax = b$ is consistent (i.e. has a solution), say it has a solution $x^*$, then for any vector $k$ of the null space, we have $A(x^*+k) = Ax^* + Ak = Ax^* + 0 = b$, so that $x^* + k$ is also a solution to the system. Since there are infinitely many vectors $k$, we have infinitely many solutions. To summarize: **Every consistent system with more unknowns than equations has infinitely many solutions.**

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you